# Print a list after being converted from string to a Label

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm creating a standard calculator with a history feature. Previous solutions will show in a label box every time the user clicks the "=" button

After converting this string:

```
string histo = (operand1 + " " + operation + " " + " " + operand2 + " = " + result);
```

To a list by using this code:

```
List<string> hist = histo.Split().ToList()
```

What I want to do next is to print it to a label box to show history. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Does it do what you expect it to? Is yoru question "How to add items to a list", or "How to print a `List<string>` to a label"?

Comment: I want to know how to print a List<string> to a label

Comment: @Grant Winney, I was searching for a way to convert strings with multiple arguments to a list and that is the code I found in another question here in StackOverflow. If I remove ".Split", an error will occur.

Comment: I'm creating a history section with an undefined size, I tried array but I learned that I have to declare its size so I used list.

Comment: You don't need to convert your string to a list and convert the list back to a string. You can simply write lbl.Text = histo; .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear and I do not think that label is a good choice to show the history. Combobox would be a better option, if you want to allow users to select items from history.

As far as your question on how to display it in a label is concerned you can use the following code. You can replace "," with Environment.NewLine.

```
lbl.Text = String.Join(",", hist);
```